# Liouville's formula

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have some questions concerning a proof of Liouville's formula:

$$W'(t)=\text{tr}(A) W(t)$$ where $W$ is the Wronskian of the homogenous ODE.

If the vectors in the columns of the fundamental matrix $X(t)$ are given by $ x_1,...,x_n$. Then it is said that $$W'(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}det(x_1,...,A(t)x_i,...,x_n)$$ where $W'$ is the time-derivative of the Wronskian of the given fundamental matrix. Until now, I am totally okay with that. Then they say: Let $X$ be the identity matrix as the fundamental matrix. And there comes my first question? Isn't the time derivative of a matrix with constant numbers always zero?

But my real problem comes when they try to trace the other cases back to this example by saying that at each time and each fundamental matrix $T(t)$, there is a matrix $C$, such that $$det(T)'(t)=(det(X) det(C))'(t)=\text{tr}(A)det(X)(t) det(C)=\text{tr}(A)det(T)
$$ How so? I mean would this not imply that $X$ (being the identity) is always a fundamental matrix of the differential equation with fundamental matrix $T(t)$? Cause I don't know how can possibly argue that the second equality sign is right, where comes this tr$(A)$ into play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused with the terminology.

Consider the initial value problem

$$ \tag 1
u'=A u, \quad u(0)=  u_0. 
$$

The matrix analogue is

$$ \tag 2 
\Psi'=A u, \quad \Psi(0)=  \Psi_0, 
$$
where $\Psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. There is a unique solution $\Psi$, given $\Psi_0$, the columns of being solutions of $ (1) $.

Liouville's formula is
$$
det \Psi(x)= det \Psi(0) \exp \left( \int_0^x Tr A \right).
$$

Here det $\Psi$ is called the Wronskian of $\Psi$.

If, $\Psi_0=I$, then $\Psi $ is called the *canonical fundamental matrix* and we write $\Psi=\Phi$. Then, we have 
$$ \Phi'=A \Phi, \quad \Phi(0)= I. $$

Any other solution matrix of $ (2) $ can be written as
$$
\Psi(x)=\Phi(x)\Psi_0.
$$

$Tr A$ comes into play in the [**Proof of Liouville's formula**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula#Proof_of_Liouville.27s_formula).